# Request-Promise throws "no auth mechanism defined" using async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, request-promise

I was just trying out async/await with `request-promise` and ran into this error:

```
RequestError: Error: no auth mechanism defined
      at new RequestError (node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:14:15)
      at Request.plumbing.callback (node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:87:29)
      at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:46:31)
      at self.callback (node_modules/request/request.js:188:22)
      at Auth.onRequest (node_modules/request/lib/auth.js:133:18)
      at Request.auth (node_modules/request/request.js:1360:14)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/routes.js:37:41)
  From previous event:
      at Request.plumbing.init (node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:36:28)
      at Request.RP$initInterceptor [as init] (node_modules/request-promise-core/configure/request2.js:41:27)
      at new Request (node_modules/request/request.js:130:8)
      at request (node_modules/request/index.js:54:10)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/routes.js:37:24)
```

It is an API endpoint that I built recently that's supposed to create a new user in MongoDB. It uses Basic Auth provided by Passport strategy, and I've tested with Postman that it works. I'm not exactly sure why this error is being thrown.

My request code (using Mocha):

```
it("creates a new user", async () => {
  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    uri: `http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}/api/users`,
    headers: {
      "User-Agent": "Request-Promise",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: {
      email: "test@domain.com",
      password: "password",
      firstName: "John",
      lastName: "Smith"
    },
    json: true
  };
  const resp = await request(options).auth(APP_ID, SIGNATURE, false);
  expect(resp).to.be.an("object");
});
```

Edit: I should probably also add that I'm using node 8.2.1 and npm 5.3.0.

Answer (score 8):

Solved for me by changing from:

```
auth: { Bearer: token }
```

to:

```
auth: { bearer: token }
```

Note the case difference on 'bearer'.

Answer (score 2):

This is usually caused by not providing suitable credentials. The code raising the error can be found [here](https://github.com/request/request/blob/b12a6245d9acdb1e13c6486d427801e123fdafae/lib/auth.js#L131). Have you verified that `APP_ID` and `SIGNATURE` are not `undefined` in your test?

Comment: Yeah, I'm certain they weren't. It's been a while since I worked on the project but I believe `APP_ID` and `SIGNATURE` were defined as module-wide constants at the top of the file. I tested using literals as well just to make sure.

Comment: This was helpful. You can't pass `auth: {}` or `auth: { username: undefined, password: undefined}`. you have to leave out the `auth` property if the request does not use authorization

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for me. I have needed to put the token inside the headers :

```
var rp = require('request-promise');

var uri = 'uri_for_my_post_request';
var token = 'access_token';
var body =  {
    title: 'My Title',
    content : 'My content'
}; 

var sendPost = async(my_uri,my_token,my_body)=>{
    var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers:{
        Authorization: ' Bearer ' + my_token           
   },
    uri: my_uri,
    body: my_body,
    json: true
};

const response = await rp(options);
console.log(response);
}

sendPost(uri,token,body);
```